# What is this line in my objdump?

Tags: winapi, assembly, disassembly

I am seeing a weird instruction in my objdump:

```
64 2e 65 78 65 fs cs gs js,pn 0x4010cb
```

When I try disassembling the opcodes manually using [this](https://defuse.ca/online-x86-assembler.htm#disassembly2), I get:

```
fs cs gs js 0x6a
```

What does this instruction mean ? What is its significance ?

Info: Assembly compiled on Windows 7 64 bit using NASM in win64 format.

Comment: That's not an instruction. It's just the text `d.exe`. You can't disassemble it and expect a sensible output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a jump instruction with a bunch of prefixes in front. It decodes like this:

- `64` is the `fs` segment override prefix. It does nothing here.
- `2e` is the `cs` segment override prefix. In front of conditional jump instructions it hints that the jump is not taken.
- `65` is the `gs` segment override prefix. It does nothing here.
- `78` is the instruction `js` “jump if sign flag set”
- `65` is the operand for this instruction.

This instruction doesn't make much sense. Since the encoding corresponds to the string `d.exe`, it could be that it is actually data instead of code. It could also be that the assembler generates useless prefixes to do some sort of alignment, but without seeing the address this instruction is at, this hypothesis cannot be tested.